# How to show a range of elements with the same class with js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making an e-store and I want 12 products to display on each page. Under the products I've created dynamic page counters (divs with corresponding numbers). The desired behaviour is: when clicking on the box with "1", you get the first 12 items with the same class, when clicking on "2", the next 12 items with the same class and so on and so on.

Given this structure:

```
<div id="products">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  <div class="item">item 11</div>
  <div class="item">item 12</div>
  <div class="item">item 13</div>
  <div class="item">item 14</div>
  <div class="item">item 15</div>
  <div class="item">item 16</div>
  <div class="item">item 17</div>
  <div class="item">item 18</div>
  <div class="item">item 19</div>
  <div class="item">item 20</div>
  <div class="item">item 21</div>
  <div class="item">item 22</div>
  <div class="item">item 23</div>
  <div class="item">item 24</div>
  <div class="item">item 25</div>
  <div class="item">item 26</div>
</div>
```

how can should I put it using js or jquery to show the corresponding 12 products?

EDIT: This is how the buttons with "1", "2", "3" are inserted depending on the number of products:

```
numItems = $('.item').length;
numPages = numItems / 12;
lastPage = numItems % 12;

for (i = 0; i <= numPages; i++) {
$('#page-counter').append('<div class="prod-page"></div>' );
}

if (lastPage >= 1) {
$('#page-counter').append('<div class="prod-page"></div>' );
}

$(".prod-page").each(function(i) {
$(this).text(++i);
});
```

As you can see, they are generated dynamically, so I should be able to apply the desired behaviour to an unspecified number of buttons.

Comment: In your question are "page1" and "page2" just different views of the same actual web page so you're just asking how you hide/show products so you only have 12 showing at a time without actually changing pages?  Or are you asking how to change your back-end infrastructure to only put 12 products into any given web page?

Comment: The first option - I don't want to reload the page, so it's rather hiding divs with the class "item" and showing the first 12, the second 12, the third twelve etc. Page1, Page2, Page3 are the buttons that I'd like to use when clicking. They look like that:
<div class="prod-page"></div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you this jquery extension [link](http://th3silverlining.com/2010/04/15/pajination-a-jquery-pagination-plugin/)

working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mBX9m/4/) with your code (items_per_page property set to 12 is what are asking)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#page_container').pajinate({items_per_page:12});
});

<div id="page_container">
    <div class="page_navigation"></div>     

  <div id="products" class="content">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  <div class="item">item 11</div>
  <div class="item">item 12</div>
  <div class="item">item 13</div>
  <div class="item">item 14</div>
  <div class="item">item 15</div>
  <div class="item">item 16</div>
  <div class="item">item 17</div>
  <div class="item">item 18</div>
  <div class="item">item 19</div>
  <div class="item">item 20</div>
  <div class="item">item 21</div>
  <div class="item">item 22</div>
  <div class="item">item 23</div>
  <div class="item">item 24</div>
  <div class="item">item 25</div>
  <div class="item">item 26</div>           
</div>
```

without extension you can do the same as you can see in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/L93Cc/3/)

```
function showItems(i){
    $("#products .item").css("display","none");
    $("#products .item").slice(i*12,i*12 + 12 ).css("display","block");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var breadCrumbs= Math.ceil($("#products .item").length/12) ;
    for(var i=0; i<breadCrumbs; i++){
        $("#breadcrumbContainer").append("<div data-item='" + i + "'>go to "+ i + "</div>");
    }

     $('#breadcrumbContainer div').click(function() {
            var value = $(this).attr("data-item");
           showItems(value);
            return false;
        });
});
```

html

```
<div id="products">
    <div id="breadcrumbContainer"></div>
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
  <div class="item">item 4</div>
  <div class="item">item 5</div>
  <div class="item">item 6</div>
  <div class="item">item 7</div>
  <div class="item">item 8</div>
  <div class="item">item 9</div>
  <div class="item">item 10</div>
  <div class="item">item 11</div>
  <div class="item">item 12</div>
  <div class="item">item 13</div>
  <div class="item">item 14</div>
  <div class="item">item 15</div>
  <div class="item">item 16</div>
  <div class="item">item 17</div>
  <div class="item">item 18</div>
  <div class="item">item 19</div>
  <div class="item">item 20</div>
  <div class="item">item 21</div>
  <div class="item">item 22</div>
  <div class="item">item 23</div>
  <div class="item">item 24</div>
  <div class="item">item 25</div>
  <div class="item">item 26</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.item{background-color:green;width:100px;}
```

if you click the divs with the content that start with "go to" you'll see visible the correct items.

Comment: Really usefull, thank you! This time I'd like to work on my existing code though - I'm a newbie and made a promise to myself to practice with my own code instead of using extensions/plugins for some time :)

Comment: if you want write only your code you can use the jquery slice function. E.g: `$( ".content .item" ).slice(0,12 )` take the first 12 items and then you can set the css display to block and none to others.

Comment: I was taking .slide into consideration before, but for me the important thing is to make it more automatic - something like:

Count the number of '.prod-page' items (how many times it occurs in the document) and for each of them create the .slice piece. 

For example, if '.prod-page' occurs 5 times, then create some kind of a loop where the .slice parameters increase by 12 every time.

I know I'm almost there, but I got stuck somehow.

Comment: All right, thnx for your time, I'll try to figure it out in the meantime for practice.

Comment: Oh my, a lot of new code for me, but anyway, it works perfect, thnx! I'm accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A more "brute-force", less elegant approach - [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GD7CL/1/).

JS

```
var itemsperpage = 5;
var pagenumber = 1;
var firstelement = 0;
var divid;

$('.holder div').on('click', function() {
    $('.holder2 div').hide();
    pagenumber = this.id.slice(-1);
    firstelement = ((pagenumber-1) * itemsperpage) + 1; 
    lastelement = (firstelement + itemsperpage);
    for(var n=firstelement; n<lastelement; n++)
       {
           $(".item:nth-child(" + n + ")").show();
        } 
});
```

Comment: It's working almost great, the only problem is that the last element of the previous page still shows as the first element on the next page. Anyway, I'll definitely take some of your code into consideration for learning purposes, thank you!

Comment: Sorry! Sorry! Sorry! I updated the code and the fiddle. Seems to work accurately now.

Comment: Ok, now it's perfect! I already accepted @Faby's answer because he came up with a solution before, but your code seems to do the same thing with less writing. Well done and thank you!

Comment: Update: in your code the number of the page doesn't load dynamically and this is a major disadvantage. Anyway, I'm already working on understanding what's been submitted here by everybody, including you, so thank you anyway! (just writing this in case somebody has a similar problem to mine).

Answer (score 1):

in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/n45GY/) there is a solution to your problem without use external plugin only jQuery code. 
the buttons are added dynamically evry 12 div items by clicking on the buttons i div.items are shown.
all jquery code you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var arr=[]
    for(i=0;i<$('.item').length;i+=12){
        arr.push(i)
        }
    arr.push($('.item').length)
    for(i=0;i<(arr.length-1);i++){
        $('<input name="" type="button" class="button" id="'+arr[i]+','+arr[i+1]+'" value="'+(arr[i]+1)+','+arr[i+1]+'">').appendTo('body')
        }
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('div.item').hide()
        var divs=$('.item')
        var range=$(this).attr('id').split(',')
        divs.slice(range[0],range[1]).css({'display':'block'})
        })
})
</script>
```

Comment: Really nice, thank you! I'm trying to understand your code now, any way I can change the 1-12, 13-24 on the buttons to 1,2,3? I tried without luck so far.